# Can I set effective date when creates a recurring payment form website in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I can create recurring payment, And effective date set as a current date automatically. But I want to change effective date when create recurring payment.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Explain what you want to do?

Comment: I want to set effective date ( recurring payment start on specific date which i give ).  Example like :  i can create recurring payment but that payment start on after 1 week not a current date.

Comment: are you using `ExpressCheckout` for `paypal`?

Comment: Yes, i am used paypal . Example like  cmd="_xclick-subscriptions" .

Comment: I had done recurring payment with paypal but with `ExpressCheckout`. First I also used `paypal component` but somewhere i stuck with this. So i suggest you to use `ExpressCheckout`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable `subscr_date` to set a start date for recurring profile.

This start date or cancellation date, will depends upon `txn_type` whether transaction is `subscr_signup` or `subscr_cancel`.

Time/Date stamp generated by PayPal, in the following format: `HH:MM:SS DD Mmm YY, YYYY PST` or `HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy z` like `22:21:09 Oct 20, 2009 PDT`

You can visit here for more information

[Subscriptions and Recurring Payments Variables](https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside)

You can also done recurring payment with paypal with `Express Checkout Api`.

[How to Create a Recurring Payments Profile with Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/)

[Handling Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/)

Comment: I had a complete recurring payment with PayPal, but just effective date is not set. I am already used subscr_date but still it's not working.     
Here is my code :
<form action = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method = "post" id = "paypal_checkout">
<input type = "hidden" name = "cmd" value = "_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type = "hidden" name = "subscr_date" value = "01/08/2016">

</form>

Comment: `subscr_date` should be in this format `"HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy z"` like this `18:13:30 Apr 17, 2012 PDT`

Comment: If this format doesn't work then try this `HH:MM:SS DD Mmm YY, YYYY PST`... I'm sure this will work